# laravel query builder enclose complex where

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have a SQL sentence like this

```
select count(*) as aggregate from books inner join apartments on apartment_id = apartments.id 
                where (date_ini <= ? and date_fin > ?) 
                or (date_ini < ? and date_fin >= ?) 
                or (date_ini >= ? and date_fin <= ?)
```

I already did the sentence in laravel

```
$searchResult=DB::table('books')->join('apartments', 'apartment_id', '=', 'apartments.id')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('date_ini', '<=', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ))
                ->where('date_fin','>', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ));
    })
    ->orwhere(function($query){
                                $query  ->where('date_ini', '<', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ))
                                        ->where('date_fin', '>=', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ));
                                })->orwhere(function($query){
                            $query->where('date_ini', '>=', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ))
                                    ->where('date_fin', '<=', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ));
                        })->paginate(2);
```

Everything is ok but I need to add one more AND condition at the end of the clause, I realized that I need to enclose all the previous clause like this and add the last AND at the end

```
select count(*) as aggregate from books inner join apartments on apartment_id = apartments.id 
                where (
                      (date_ini <= ? and date_fin > ?) 
                or (date_ini < ? and date_fin >= ?) 
                or (date_ini >= ? and date_fin <= ?)
                )and col1=?
```

I dont know how to enclose all that in query builder, any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your boolean conditions in a nested *where* clause and add the first where clause that will act as an *AND*, like:

```
$searchResult=DB::table('books')->join('apartments', 'apartment_id', '=', 'apartments.id')
 ->where('col1','=','foobar') 
 ->where(function($queryContainer){
    $queryContainer->where(function($query){
        $query->where('date_ini', '<=', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ))
                ->where('date_fin','>', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ));
            })
            ->orwhere(function($query){
                                $query  ->where('date_ini', '<', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ))
                                        ->where('date_fin', '>=', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ));
            })
            ->orwhere(function($query){
                            $query->where('date_ini', '>=', Input::get( 'desdeGet' ))
                                    ->where('date_fin', '<=', Input::get( 'hastaGet' ));
            });
    })
  ->paginate(2);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, it works!! The only thing is I had to delete the last }) to work. Thanks again.